# Wake up a thread without kernel support

Tags: linux, multithreading, ipc

Is there any mechanism through which I can wake up a thread in another process without going through the kernel? The waiting thread might spin in a loop, no problem (each thread is pegged to a separate core), but in my case the sending thread has to be quick, and can't afford to go through the kernel to wake up the waiting thread.

Comment: Are you asking about how fast `sem_post` is, or are you looking for a way to coordinate threads without help from the kernel?

Comment: Re-reading the question, is this just about how to do "inter-process communication" without a kernel call?

Comment: Also, what platform (Linux, POSIX, Windows)? (It makes a difference for threading and IPC mechanisms.)

Comment: Dan Cecile, it is interthread communication. He wants to do this WITHOUT help by OS. There is a portable (any OS; fixed CPU arch) way of doing this (write a spinlock); the only OS-dependent thing is CPU binding; but most OS allow user to bind thread to CPU. And reading the question we can assume that OS supports threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if the other thread is sleeping (not on CPU). To wake up such thread you need to change its state into "RUNNING" by calling scheduler which is part of the kernel.

Yes, you can syncronize two threads or processes if both are running on different CPUs, and if there is shared memory between them. You should bind all threads to different CPUs. Then you may use spinlock:[`pthread_spin_lock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_spin_lock.html) and [`pthread_spin_unlock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_spin_unlock.html) functions from optional part of POSIX's Pthread (`'(ADVANCED REALTIME THREADS)'`; `[THR SPI]`); or any of custom spinlock. Custom spinlock most likely will use some atomic operations and/or memory barriers.

Sending thread will change the value in memory, which is checked in loop by receiver thread.

E.g.

init:

```
pthread_spinlock_t lock;
pthread_spin_lock(&lock);  // close the "mutex"
```

then start threads.

waiting thread:

```
{
pthread_spin_lock(&lock); // wait for event;
work();
}
```

main thread:

```
{
do_smth();
pthread_spin_unlock(&lock); // open the mutex; other thread will see this change
 //  in ~150 CPU ticks (checked on Pentium4 and Intel Core2 single socket systems);
 // time of the operation itself is of the same order; didn't measure it.
continue_work();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To signal to another **process** that it should continue, without forcing the sender to spend time in a kernel call, one mechanism comes to mind right away. Without kernel calls, all a process can do is modify memory; so the solution is [inter-process shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory). Once the sender writes to shared memory, the receiver should see the change without any explicit kernel calls, and naive polling by the receiver should work fine.

One cheap (but maybe not cheap enough) alternative is delegating the sending to a helper thread in the same process, and have the helper thread make a proper inter-process "semaphore release" or pipe write call.

Comment: pipe is OS-based method. There are syscalls `write` and `read` for every synchronization.

Comment: @osgx: Does an asynchronous I/O library like [libeio](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libeio.html) use vanilla `write` and `read` calls?

Comment: The classic UNIX pipe is OS-assisted construction. For libeio: "It is very portable and relies only on POSIX threads.", so it is the "Another alternative  is delegating". Check [the lines 918 and 934 in this file](http://cvs.schmorp.de/libeio/eio.c?revision=1.102&view=markup)

Comment: @osgx: I was looking there too, at the same time. I've revised my answer.

Comment: Dan Cecile, but this library is good for cases when programmer can't afford any syscall in sending thread and can afford rather long (in term of 10k-100k CPU ticks) delay from sending to receiving the event. So it is cheap for sending thread; and no so fast in delivering message.

Comment: Fair enough; it wouldn't be a high-performance solution. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to avoid using the kernel in order to avoid kernel-related overheads. Most of such overheads are context-switch related. Here is a demonstration of one way to accomplish what you need using signals without spinning, and without context switches:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void sigRtHandler(int sig) {
    cout << "Recevied signal" << endl;
}

int main() {
    constexpr static int kIter = 100000;
    thread t([]() {
        signal(SIGRTMIN, sigRtHandler);
        for (int i = 0; i < kIter; ++i) {
            usleep(1000);
        }
        cout << "Done" << endl;
    });
    usleep(1000);   // Give child time to setup signal handler.
    auto handle = t.native_handle();
    for (int i = 0; i < kIter; ++i)
        pthread_kill(handle, SIGRTMIN);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

If you run this code, you'll see that the child thread keeps receiving the SIGRTMIN. While the process is running, if you look in the files /proc/(PID)/task/*/status for this process, you'll see that parent thread does not incur context switches from calling pthread_kill().

The advantage of this approach is that the waiting thread doesn't need to spin. If the waiting thread's job is not time-sensitive, this approach allows you to save CPU.